Integration of function of independent random variables
Let $X,Y,Z:(\Omega_1,\mu_1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be independent random variables, and $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a "good" function.
If we denote $Y^\prime:(\Omega_2,\mu_2)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and  $Z^\prime:(\Omega_3,\mu_3)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be copies of $Y$ and $Z$ respectively. Do we have the following identity (called probability decoupling) $$\int_{\Omega_1}F\Big(X(\omega),Y(\omega),Z(\omega)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_1(\omega)=\int_{\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3}F\Big(X(\omega_1),Y^\prime(\omega_2),Z^\prime(\omega_3)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_1(\omega_1)\mathrm{d}\mu_2(\omega_2)\mathrm{d}\mu_3(\omega_3)\quad ?$$
It seems that this is an elementary exercise but I'm quite embarrassed by my poor knowledge of probability theory. Intuitively this should be true, since once $X,Y,Z$ are independent, and one may think them as different coordinate components, so the above identity is something like Fubini theorem.
This question arises from my reading on Jean Bourgain's paper $\textit{Bounded orthogonal systems and the Λ(p)-set problem}$, a key step in his paper is a decoupling argument. The function $F$ appearing in his paper is quite complicated so I do not write it here.
Any suggestions will be helpful, thank you!

"Independence" is only defined for random variables in the same probability space. So what does it mean for $Y'$ and $Z'$ to be independent?

@Wei Thank you for pointing that out, it was already edited.

The identity is true.
If $F$ has the special form $f(x,y,z) = A(x)B(y)C(z)$ (with $A,B,C$ bounded and measurable) then the identity follows directly from independence.
The functional form of the monotone class theorem now immediately implies the identity for bounded jointly measurable $F$.
The boundedness of $F$ can be relaxed by suitable truncation.

After referring to some textbooks I got the point. Maybe someone else will have the same problem as me. I posed my answer here:
Let $\mathrm{d}P_{(X,Y,Z)}$ be the probability law (or distribution) of $X,Y,Z$, meaning that $\mathrm{d}P_{(X,Y,Z)}$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$\mathrm{d}P_{(X,Y,Z)}(A):=\mu_1\Big(\Big\{\omega\in\Omega_1:\big(X(\omega_1),Y(\omega_1),Z(\omega_1)\big)\in A\Big\}\Big).$$
Since $X,Y,Z$ are independent, one has $$\mathrm{d}P_{(X,Y,Z)}=\mathrm{d}P_{X}\times \mathrm{d}P_{Y}\times \mathrm{d}P_{Z},$$
where $\mathrm{d}P_{X},\mathrm{d}P_{Y},\mathrm{d}P_{Z}$ are distributions of $X,Y,Z$ respectively. Now the integration $\int_{\Omega_1}F(X,Y,Z)$ can be rewritten as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F(x,y,z)\ \mathrm{d}P_{(X,Y,Z)}(x,y,z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x,y,z)\ \mathrm{d}P_{X}(x)\ \mathrm{d}P_{Y}(y)\ \mathrm{d}P_{Z}(z).$$
On the other hand, for $\int_{\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3}F\Big(X(\omega_1),Y^\prime(\omega_2),Z^\prime(\omega_3)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_1(\omega_1)\mathrm{d}\ \mu_2(\omega_2)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_3(\omega_3)$, one has
$$\int_{\Omega_1}F\Big(X(\omega_1),Y^\prime(\omega_2),Z^\prime(\omega_3)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_1(\omega_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}F\Big(x,Y^\prime(\omega_2),Z^\prime(\omega_3)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}P_X(x).$$
The above identity also holds for $\omega_2,\omega_3$. Fubini theorem gives that $$\int_{\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3}F\Big(X(\omega_1),Y^\prime(\omega_2),Z^\prime(\omega_3)\Big)\ \mathrm{d}\mu_1(\omega_1)\mathrm{d}\mu_2(\omega_2)\mathrm{d}\mu_3(\omega_3)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F(x,y,z)\ \mathrm{d}P_{X}(x)\ \mathrm{d}P_{Y}(y)\ \mathrm{d}P_{Z}(z).$$
Here one uses that $\mathrm{d}P_Y=\mathrm{d}P_{Y^\prime}$ since $Y^\prime$ is a copy of $Y$, similar for $Z,Z^\prime$.
